# How to use enable_load_extension()?

Tags: python, macos, sqlite

I got the following error when I use `enable_load_extension()`:

> AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension'

I also see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#f1), but sqlite3 should come with Python. How to reinstall it with the correct option?

> The sqlite3 module is not built with loadable extension support by default, because some platforms (notably Mac OS X) have SQLite libraries which are compiled without this feature. To get loadable extension support, you must pass –enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions to configure.

Answer (score 8):

Check if your sqlite3 was built with extension loading enabled. You can check by running the executable and check via the command `.dbconfig`

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version ...
...
sqlite> .dbconfig
...
load_extension on
```

If that's not the case, install sqlite via Homebrew or compile from source [see docs](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html).

Then, you want to build Python from scratch with the appropriate sqlite3 library linked. It's pretty easy using pyenv. Specific build options can be provided via the `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS` environment variable (details [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/tree/master/plugins/python-build)) and setting `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` (see [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems))

Building with pyenv assuming sqlite3 was installed via Homebrew (check `which sqlite3`and `brew info sqlite` for details on which versions are installed and where):

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=\$(brew --prefix openssl)" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include" \
pyenv install 3.8.2
```

You may also have to meet some of Python3's dependencies (e.g. on [macos](https://devguide.python.org/setup/#macos) `brew install openssl xz gdbm`)

Building Python manually is also pretty straightforward and follows a similar pattern. Once dependencies are met, download the tarball with the desired version and set the compile options to enable sqlite3 extension loading (and telling make where to find your newly compiled SQLite build):

```
./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)
LDFLAGS="-L<path-to-sqlite>" \
CPPFLAGS="-I<path-to-sqlite>" \
make -j2
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it helpful. I'd like to suggest updating it with some extra info: You should have the homebrew openssl in you path, for example - do
brew info openssl
and then add the path to your .bashrc:

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

If your Python `sqlite3` module comes without support for loading extensions, you can fix this by using the [`sqlean.py`](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean.py) package.

It's a drop-in replacement for the standard library's `sqlite3` module, already precompiled for Windows, Linux and macOS, so you don't need to compile anything.

```
pip install sqlean.py
```

```py
import sqlean as sqlite3

# has the same API as the default `sqlite3` module
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute("create table employees(id, name)")
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the folder where Python is installed and reinstalled it.

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/using/configure.html%5D) and [dev guide](https://devguide.python.org/getting-started/setup-building/) you can find more on the compiler's configurations.

Step 1: keeps track of your current configurations

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_config_vars('CONFIG_ARGS')[0]
```

Step 2: reinstall (from inside the python's folder!)

```
Python-3.X $ ./configure --with-pydebug \ # for example & add your previous configuration
                         --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions # <-

Python-3.X $ make -s -j2          # amount of processors
Python-3.X $ sudo make altinstall # doesn't overwrite previous installations
```

Step 3: check again the configuration with Step 1

```
Python-3.X $ ./python # check the prompt
>>> import sysconfig #    etc
```

Step 4: update paths, environment variables, etc

For more info about amount of processors and `altinstall` just look for ex at the link of the *dev guide* above, are not mandatory it just depends on your personal needs.

In the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.enable_load_extension) documentation you can find a working example of `enable_load_extension`.

Answer (score 0):

I use **pyenv** over **macos** and this worked for me.

```bash
$ brew install sqlite3
$ PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions" \
    LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib" \
    CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include" \
    pyenv install <PYTHON_VERSION>
```

Source: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1702#issuecomment-1818499967